# How to relabel axis ticks for a matplotlib heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am following [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_interp.html) to produce a heat map. Would it be possible to relabel the values over the X-axis, and add a constant to it.

Instead of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 on the x-axis, I would like to have, for example, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can label the x and y axes by using the keyword argument `extent` in the calls to `imshow`.  Here is some documentation,

```
extent : scalars (left, right, bottom, top), optional, default: None
Data limits for the axes.  The default assigns zero-based row,
column indices to the `x`, `y` centers of the pixels.
```

working off the example you linked, you can do the following,

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(5, 5)
plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(A, interpolation='nearest')
plt.grid(True)

left = 4.5
right = 9.5
bottom = 4.5
top = -0.5
extent = [left, right, bottom, top]

plt.figure(2)
plt.imshow(A, interpolation='nearest', extent=extent)
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

This will change only the x-axis labels.  Note that you have to account for the fact that the default labels the pixels while `extent` labels the whole axis (hence the factors of 0.5).  Also note that the default labelling of the y-axis in `imshow` increases from top to bottom (going from 0 at the top to 4 at the bottom), this means our `bottom` will be larger than our `top` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple add the constant via for-loop or list comprehension and use it as new axis label, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

CONST = 10

x = range(10)
y = range(10)
labels = [i+CONST for i in x]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x-value + 10')


# set ticks followed by setting labels
ax.set_xticks(range(10))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I added it to my [matplotlib gallery in IPython notebooks](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/matplotlib-gallery/blob/master/ipynb/formatting.ipynb#Adding-a-constant-value-to-axis-labels) here with other examples if it is useful:

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to relabel the current plot (click on it to select it) you use the `xticks()` function (Note the `arange()` upper limit needs to be one more than the desired maximum) - e.g. from iPython/Python:

```
xticks(arange(0,5),arange(5,10))
```

If you wanted to modify the python script file then you would use:

```
plt.xticks(arange(0,5),arange(5,10))
```